# Having trouble pushing an existing repository to GitHub

Tags: git, github

Here is what I did which worked locally.

1. `mkdir git_practice`
2. `cd git_practice`
3. `git init, echo "Hello Git and GitHub" >> README.txt`
4. `git add README.txt`
5. `git commit -m "First commit"`

I then created a repository and did this:

1. `git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxxxxx/git_practice.git`
2. `git branch -M main, git push -u origin main`

After the push git stalls out I guess? When I try to close git it says processes are running in session: but those processes never finish and nothing gets pushed to my GitHub repository.

Comment: here is a SS: https://ibb.co/whyYCMc

Comment: Are you using Windows Git? If so, which version?

Comment: @torek git version 2.32.0.windows.1

Comment: OK - you've run into a bug that's new in that version. Apparently downgrading to 2.30 gets around it, or you can do some sort of pre-authentication or use some other shell or something, but the way I'd probably try to work around it myself is to use ssh instead of https.